# How to Implement logout functionality by using jsonwebtoken in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, json-web-token

we know, that first approached is to delete cookie of browser.

> But I want to know how to destroy token from server side or how to check logout functionality from server side.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible using JWT. 
Instead you can blacklist the token.

Take a look at https://auth0.com/blog/blacklist-json-web-token-api-keys/

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution I've been thinking about is implementing a throttling mechanism to limit how many times the token can be used within its usage window. I think you would only need the last token used for a user and to invalidate it set the count to its max.